# Cannot import 'swish' in 'tensorflow.python.keras.activations'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I am running a jupyter notebook from an Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda 3), and I am trying to use tensorflow keras.

I am trying to run the import statement:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d23f18c08372> in <module>
      4 from keras.models import Model
      5 
----> 6 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
      7 
      8 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     12 import sys as _sys
     13 
---> 14 from . import activations
     15 from . import applications
     16 from . import backend

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\activations\__init__.py in <module>
     21 from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import softplus
     22 from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import softsign
---> 23 from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import swish
     24 from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import tanh
     25 

ImportError: cannot import name 'swish' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.activations' (C:\Users\FlamePrinz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations.py)
```

Comment: Somehow your TensorFlow installation is broken, try reinstalling, or using the official wheels (not anaconda).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an older question, but I ended up taking Dr. Snoopy's suggestion uninstalling and reinstalling TensorFlow which solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
from keras.layers import Activation
get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Activation(swish)})
```

***swish*** function needs to be passed into activation class to actually build it.

And then you can do

```
model.add(Dense(64, activation = "swish"))
```

Comment: Sorry but your answer has nothing to do  with the question, the error happens when importing tf.keras.

Comment: Isn't the cause of error happening due to absence of swish activation in `tensorflow.python.keras.activations`?

Comment: Yes, but it should be there, your answer does not address that problem at all.

Comment: I offered an alternate solution just in case that function isn't there.

Comment: No, this is not an alternate solution, it is not a solution  at all, the problem happens when importing tf.keras, means that the tensorflow installation itself is broken.

Comment: why is then the error trace stopped exactly at line 23, not earlier? Doesn't it imply that swish is not there? The user is using an older version of tf and/or keras IMHO.

Comment: Did you notice that the user is not importing swish directly, but it is being imported internally inside tf.keras? Why do you think that means?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"?

Comment: `from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import swish` happens inside `tensorflow\keras\activations\__init__.py`, not in the user's code, it is happening inside tensorflow itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can download swish activation from pypi. Try the following:

1. `pip install swish-activation`
2. `import swish_package`
3. `from swish_package import swish`